# Regard input string as defined array name in BASH

Tags: arrays, bash

I am currently working on a script that receives the input string and then use it as the defined array name. But I stuck with this, thanks in advance

```
a=(1 2 3)
b=(4 5 6)
c=(7 8 9)
```

if input from user is "a", I want the result_array will be like (1 2 3)?

```
a=(1 2 3); b=(4 5 6); input="a"; result_array=("${${input}[@]}"); echo ${result_array[@]}

bash: ${${input}[@]}: bad substitution
```

All I want is: `result_array=("${${input}[@]}") => result_array=("${a[@]}") = (1 2 3)`

Note: I dont want to use IF statements like "if input = a or b or c, result_array= a or b or c", because I have to do this step many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a=(1 2 3); 
b=(4 5 6);
# ...
input="a"; # get the user input
result_array=${input}[@];
echo \(${!result_array}\)
```

will print:

```
(1 2 3)
```

Comment: great! that's what I need. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Case is more simple than IF in this case. Also faster.

```
#!/bin/bash

case "$1" in
    a) result_array=(1 2 3);;
    b) result_array=(4 5 6);;
    c) result_array=(7 8 9);;
esac

echo ${result_array[@]}
```

I also made a script calculate the array according to char ascii positions compered to a, since you said you don't like to use IF.

```
#!/bin/bash

# a ascii value
a_num=$(echo a|od -t d1 | awk '{printf "%s" ,$2}')

# input ascii value
ascii=$(echo $1|od -t d1 | awk '{printf "%s" ,$2}')

multiplier=$((($ascii - $a_num) * 3))

result_array=( $((1 + $multiplier)) $((2 + $multiplier)) $((3 + $multiplier)))

echo ${result_array[@]}
```

Ouputs:

```
./ascii.sh a
1 2 3
./ascii.sh b
4 5 6
./ascii.sh c
7 8 9
./ascii.sh w
67 68 69
./ascii.sh x
70 71 72
```

Comment: although it is not what I want at the beginning, I like your idea (using "case" to handle this situation). Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 ways to do this. Starting from

```
a=(1 2 3)
b=(4 5 6)
# ...
input="a"
```

1. use a [nameref](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameters) (bash v4.4)

   ```
   declare -n input                 # set the "nameref" attribute for the variable
   result_array=( "${input[@]}")
   printf "%s\n" "${result_array[@]}"
   ```

   ```
   1
   2
   3
   ```

   To "reuse" the `input` variable to point to `b`, `input=b` is insufficient. That sets `input[0]` (and hence `a[0]`) to "b". You need use `declare -n input=b`
2. use [indirect expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) (as @tso did in his answer)

   ```
   tmp="${input}[@]"           # a string that looks like array expansion
   result_array=( "${!tmp}" )
   printf "%s\n" "${result_array[@]}"
   ```

   ```
   1
   2
   3
   ```